# SQL Query Using VB Fields Does Not Return Results

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have been trying for several hours to figure out my correct syntax for a MSSQL query using fields. If I use the first line of code, I get no results.

```
Dim selectStatement As String = "SELECT * from tires.dbo.sales WHERE date BETWEEN '" & Reports.CalStartDate.SelectionStart & "'" & " and " & Reports.CalEndDate.SelectionEnd & "'"""
```

(I have two text boxes that show the contents of `Reports.CalStartDate.SelectionStart` and `Reports.CalStartDate.SelectionEnd` and they show the correct characters, exactly the same as the query that works.

If I use this (hardcoded) line, I get the expected results.

```
Dim selectStatement As String = "SELECT * from tires.dbo.sales where date between '03/21/2015' and'03/23/2015'"
```

Here is my mssql create script:

```
USE [tires]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sales](
[date] [date] NULL,
[cust_id] [int] NULL,
[tire_id] [int] NULL,
[qty] [int] NULL,
[cost_ea] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[retail_ea] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[plate] [nchar](10) NULL,
[mileage] [nchar](10) NULL,
[service] [nchar](30) NULL,
[serv_price] [nchar](10) NULL,
[total] [nchar](10) NULL,
[notes] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[custphone] [nchar](10) NULL,
[service2] [nchar](30) NULL,
[serv2_price] [nchar](10) NULL,
[inv_no] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[tire_id2] [int] NULL,
[qty2] [int] NULL,
[cost_ea2] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[retail_ea2] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[tire_id3] [int] NULL,
[qty3] [int] NULL,
[cost_ea3] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[retail_ea3] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[tire1w] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[tire2w] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[tire3w] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[tax] [nchar](10) NULL,
[fet] [nchar](10) NULL,
[labor] [nchar](10) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_sales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[inv_no] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: What's the value of `selectStatement` after the concatenation?

Comment: I am not sure how to tell what that value is. If I had the tools to show that value, that would be AMAZING!

Comment: Add a breakpoint. Hint: DEBUG mode

Comment: Thanks! I will try to figure that out...

Comment: wewesthemenace.... THANKS! I never thought about adding a breakpoint to see the value of the query. That nailed it. thanks for the fast response!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. I don't know what to do with this question, I suggest you delete it?

Comment: I will leave it. Using fields with SQL queries can be tricky. By leaving this out there, it might help others to suggest using a breakpoint and looking at the select statement in the same manner that the MSSQL server sees the query. Hopefully this helps another user someday. I am not sure how to mark your answer as the correct one. I am still "green" when it comes to stackoverflow.

Comment: My comment is not necessarily an answer so I can't just put it and have you accept it. Anyway, it's your choice.

Comment: Some advice: even without debugging its clear you had lacking ' in your query ;). However you should chance your query into a parametrized query. You'll catch such errors as this faster (because the combination of ' and " will be less) - plus you make your code safer/more secure.